# Couldn't connect to MySQL: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'

Tags: mysql, docker

I am working on UBUNTU and the container was created successfully with the following  command:

```
docker run -d -p 3000:3306 --name mysql  -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456789 -e MYSQL_DATABASE=docker_db -e MYSQL_USER=docker_user -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=0000 mysql:5.7
```

but once trying to connect to the database using:

```
mysql -u root -h localhost -P 3000 -p
```

I am getting this error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, when the client try to connect on localhost, it will use the socket and not TCP and will ignore the port parameter.

I think you have a MySQL up and running locally and it's why you have the access denied error instead of this one:

```
❯ mysql -u root -h localhost -P 3000 -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

By changing the command for:

```
❯ mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3000 -p

Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 2
Server version: 5.7.26 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
[...]
```

Will use the TCP connection on the IP/port you give.